# best SQLServer client for ubuntu 12.08 which can also help generating an ER Diagram

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu-12.04

I need to connect to a sql server 2008 from my ubuntu machine, and i need to analyse all the column available in the DB i am connecting to (ER Diagram??), can any one suggest a tool to do that , have tried squirrel already.

Comment: and the problem with squirrel was? To analyse all the columns, is it sufficient to simply have a flat list of all columns, tables and data types? Does your source database have foriegn keys? You'll need these at least to automatically generate an ER diagram.

Comment: The problem with squirrel was that i could not find a way to generate the ER diagram of the complete DB , yes if some command can give me a flat list that will be useful too , And answer to your last question , Yes , they do have foreign keys

Answer (score 1):

I can't help you with a free ubuntu tool to generate an ER diagrma, but...

this SQL lists columns with data types:

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1032279-2863-1.aspx#bm1034068

```
SELECT table_schema, table_name, column_name, data_type, character_maximum_length,
is_nullable, column_default, numeric_precision, numeric_scale
FROM information_schema.columns
ORDER BY table_schema, table_name, ordinal_position
```

This SQL lists all foreign keys:

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1151/identify-all-of-your-foreign-keys-in-a-sql-server-database/

```
SELECT C.TABLE_CATALOG [PKTABLE_QUALIFIER], 
   C.TABLE_SCHEMA [PKTABLE_OWNER], 
   C.TABLE_NAME [PKTABLE_NAME], 
   KCU.COLUMN_NAME [PKCOLUMN_NAME], 
   C2.TABLE_CATALOG [FKTABLE_QUALIFIER], 
   C2.TABLE_SCHEMA [FKTABLE_OWNER], 
   C2.TABLE_NAME [FKTABLE_NAME], 
   KCU2.COLUMN_NAME [FKCOLUMN_NAME], 
   RC.UPDATE_RULE, 
   RC.DELETE_RULE, 
   C.CONSTRAINT_NAME [FK_NAME], 
   C2.CONSTRAINT_NAME [PK_NAME], 
   CAST(7 AS SMALLINT) [DEFERRABILITY] 
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS C 
   INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE KCU 
     ON C.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = KCU.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA 
        AND C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = KCU.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
   INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS RC 
     ON C.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = RC.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA 
        AND C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = RC.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
   INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS C2 
     ON RC.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = C2.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA 
        AND RC.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME = C2.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
   INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE KCU2 
     ON C2.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = KCU2.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA 
        AND C2.CONSTRAINT_NAME = KCU2.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
        AND KCU.ORDINAL_POSITION = KCU2.ORDINAL_POSITION 
WHERE  C.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY'
```

Comment: Thanks for your help , i was able to figure out a way to generate ER from squirrel itself

Comment: I suggest you explain in more detail and accept your own answer. How many times have you searched for a question, found it, and it was unanswered?